# Prove that if $b_n \to L$ then $a^{b_n} \to a^L$ with $a \in \mathbb{N}$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

What I have so far is that for any $\epsilon>0$ there is $n \geq N$ such that $|b_n-L|< \epsilon.$ Then,

$$
|a^{b_n}-a^L| = a^L|a^{b_n-L}-1|
$$

Now I know that I have to make the above less than epsilon but I do not know what the next step is. Any hints?

Comment: You wanna make $|a^{b_n}-a^L|$ smaller than $\epsilon$. For this, you need $|a^x-1|$ smaller than $\frac{\epsilon}{a^L}$, where $x=b_n-L$...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what theorems you're allowed to use. So I'll try to use as few results as I can manage.

---

First, a few preliminary results:

(1) Put $x_n=b_n-l$. Clearly, $x_n\rightarrow 0$ since $b_n\rightarrow l$.

Proof.

$|x_n|=|b_n-l|<\varepsilon$.

(2) If $s_n\rightarrow s$, then $Cs_n\rightarrow Cs$ (where $C$ is a constant).

Proof.

Let $s_n\rightarrow s$ and $C>0$. $\exists N\in \mathbb{N}$ so that $\forall n\geq N \Rightarrow |s_n-s|\leq \frac{\varepsilon}{C}$. For that same $N$, we have
$$|Cs_n-Cs|=C|s_n-s|<C\frac{\varepsilon}{C}=\varepsilon $$

---

Now Let $x_{n_k}$ and $x_{n_j}$ be the subsequences of positive and negative numbers of $x_n$, respectively. Still, $x_{n_k},x_{n_j}\rightarrow 0$ since $x_n\rightarrow 0$. (if either subsequence didn't exists or it represents only a finite amount of points, we'd just omit the parts of the proof with them).

Let $f(x_n)=a^{x_n}$. I will show that $f(x_{n_k}), f(x_{n_j})\rightarrow 1$.

Proof.

Clearly, $f(x_{n_k})>1>f(x_{n_j})$. Suppose $\exists \varepsilon>0$ so that for any $N\in \mathbb{N}$ we choose it follows that $\forall n\geq N$ $f(x_{n_k})>1+\varepsilon$. then we have
$$a^{x_{n_k}}>1+\varepsilon $$
$$x_{n_k} \log(a)>\log(1+\varepsilon) $$
as $x_{n_k}\rightarrow 0$ (i.e. taking the limit of the above expression), we have
$$0>\log(1+\varepsilon) $$
$$1>1+\varepsilon$$
$$0>\varepsilon$$
A contradiction. Hence, $\exists N\in \mathbb{N}$ so that $\forall n\geq N$ we have
$$1+\varepsilon>f(x_{n_k})>1$$
$$\varepsilon>f(x_{n_k})-1>0$$
$$\varepsilon>|f(x_{n_k})-1|>0$$
Therefore, $f(x_{n_k})\rightarrow 1$. We can do a similar argument to show that
$1-\varepsilon<f(x_{n_j})<1$. (I'll leave that to you for practice).

Now, since $f(x_{n_k}),f(x_{n_j})\rightarrow 1 \Rightarrow f(x_n)\rightarrow 1$. 
That would follow, since past $N=\max\{N_k,N_j\}$ (Note: $N_k$ and $N_j$ denote the constants such that $\forall n$ bigger than them $f(x_{n_k})$ and $f(x_{n_j})\rightarrow 1$, respectively), it would follow that $\forall n\geq N \Rightarrow$ 
$$1-\varepsilon<f(x_n)<1+\varepsilon $$
$$-\varepsilon<f(x_n)-1<\varepsilon $$
$$|f(x_n)-1|<\varepsilon$$

Using (2) in our preliminaries, it follows that $a^lf(x_n)\rightarrow a^l$. In other words, $$a^la^{x_n}=a^{b_n}\rightarrow a^l.$$
Exactly what we wanted to prove.

Comment: It might be overkill, But I was trying to use as few theorems as possible since I do not know your background.